# Custom filter executes infinitely

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have made this custom filter to check whether a user is logged in or not, but this results in a redirect loop.

```
public class CustomeFilterForAdmin : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Type"] != null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary { 
                    { "controller", "Admin" }, { "action", "Index" }
                });
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "controller", "Login" }, { "action", "Index" }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the page you're redirecting the user to, is protected with the same `CustomeFilterForAdmin` filter

Comment: Also, don't rely on the mere existence of some cookie to authorize users, as it can't be considered an auth mechanism. Use the proper `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` filter instead.

Comment: recursion is a method that contains a recursion.

Comment: [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] where to use. is it for admin controller

Comment: " is it for admin controller"...no, you can change the role to whatever role(s) you need to authorise on each method. What Haim wrote is just an example. If you don't understand the usage of that attribute, you can read about it, Microsoft have documented it online, with lots of sample code.

Comment: Thanks   Adyson . could you please give details of online links of documented for the same